# Network path was not found while joining domain (samba)

Tags: windows, networking, domain, path

I have my AC server on 10.0.0.2 (debian, samba installed). From PC1 (notebook, windows 7 professional) I can easy join my domain and all things are good. But from PC2 (windows 7 professional too) I have one simple problem. I try to join to domain, type credentials for Administrator, then after while I see error:

> Network path was not found

Firewall: off 
Antivirus: off

Important things from ipconfig/all:

> DHCP on . . . . . . . . . . : YES
>   IPv4 adress . . . . . . . . . . .. . : 10.0.0.15(Recommanded)
>   Server DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
>   Servers DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
>   . . . . . . . . . . .. . . . . . . . . 8.8.8.8
>   Server WINS. . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
>   NetBIOS overTcpip . . . . . . . : On

I can ping 10.0.0.2. 
I can browse internet on PC2. 
 
Nslookup domain.local:

> (root)  ??? unknown type 41 ???
>   Server:  UnKnown
>   Address: 10.0.0.2
>   Name:   domain.local
>   Address:  192.168.1.26

What I have already tried? 
Disabling ipv6, 
Enable/Disable NetBios over TCP/IP 
Changing computer name 
Restarting some services from services.msc (ex. dhcp client) 
Rebooting server/client 
Searching for some strange network adapters, found nothing 
Time zone is good in server and client 
ipconfig/flushdns 
Sharing in windows is enabled 
Disabling some services in windows

Totally, I have tried anything that I found on Internet, nothing actually works.
PC1 joins without any problems. 
Please help.

Edit: smb.conf:

```
[global]
    workgroup = DOMAIN
    realm = domain.local
    netbios name = DEBIAN
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
    server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.local/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
[Profiles]
    path = /srv/samba/Profiles/
    read only = no
    store dos attributes = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    profile acls = yes
    csc policy = disable
```

Comment: You haven't shown a testparm output or the smb.conf file from your samba box. Those are very important for figuring this out.

Comment: I would remove 8.8.8.8 as a secondary DNS server. On a network with a private domain, you should only have DNS servers who has your domain assign to clients, otherwise you may have some complications such as failure to resolve your domain. I would suggest you let only 10.0.0.2 as the DNS server, clear cache and try again.

Comment: could you show us a result of a nslookup to the name of the domain please?

Comment: Hi,
thanks for advices.
I tried without this 8.8.8.8 DNS server and got the same error. I show nslookup above I think.

I will show smb.conf tommorow, unfortunetly I can't do this today. But, other computer can join, so how could this be samba fault?

Comment: Remove the wins server please and the netbios setting, reboot, and try again

Comment: @yagmoth555 I tried this already, didn't work